# jQuery find iframe document

Tags: iframe, iframe-app

I need to find the iframe value 
     
     
          var myContent=$("#myiframe").contents().find(".spl");
          alert(myContent);
     
    but its not working please help me

Comment: put that code inside window.load

Answer (score 0):

First of all your selector looks corrupt, if you're pointing to an element with id use:

```
.find("#spl");
```

else if it's a class use:

```
.find(".spl");
```

You need to wait till iframe is loaded so

```
$("#myiframe").load(function () {
    var myContent = $("#myiframe").contents().find("#spl");
    alert(myContent);
});
```

Comment: yes sorry by mistake I have put something wrong there and I have correct that, but your code is also not working...